# Mudar id children para outro id

Tags: cakephp

Fiz um painel com algumas funções do tree, editar, mover e apagar.
Até então meu apagar está funcionando quando eu quero apagar uma coisa específica sem filhos. O problema é que, quando eu apago um item que tem filhos, ele apaga todos o filhos juntos, e minha intenção era que ele mudasse os parent_id dos filhos do item que vai ser apagado, para o item que eu selecionei na lista.

PS: esse `$this->request->data['Navigation']['childs']` é o id que eu tenho um menu com uma lista retornando todos os ids que tenho disponíveis para que a pessoa possa mudá-los.

```
public function apagar($id){
        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            empty($this->request->data['Navigation']['childs']) ? null : $this->request->data['Navigation']['childs'];
            $this->Navigation->updateAll(array(
            'Navigation.parent_id' => $id,
             ), array(
            'Navigation.parent_id' => $this->request->data['Navigation']['childs'],
            ));
            $this->Navigation->id = $id;
            $this->Navigation->delete();
            $this->Session->setFlash('Menu Apagado!');
            return $this->redirect('/navegacao');
        } else {
            $tree = $this->Navigation->generateTreeList(null, null, null, '   - ');
            unset($tree[$id]);
            $this->set('tree', $tree);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note que esta linha abaixo não resulta em nada.

```
empty($this->request->data['Navigation']['childs']) ? null : $this->request->data['Navigation']['childs'];
```

Pra ser sincero, não entendi muito bem como é essa sua lógica de apagar ou não o registro. Mas ao que parece, sua intenção era utilizar o valor da sua coluna `childs` para fazer esta atualização. Então você precisa fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
if (!empty($this->request->data['Navigation']['childs'])) {
    // Possui filhos
    $this->Navigation->updateAll(
                array('Navigation.parent_id' => $id),
                array('Navigation.parent_id' => $this->request->data['Navigation']['childs'])
    );
} else {
    // Não possui filhos
}
```

Comment: Ele muda o parent_id, mas não exclui o id que o cara clica, aí fica os ids mudados, mas o id que eu cliquei para excluir continua lá.

Comment: Experimente trocar para `$this->Navigation->delete($id)`.

Comment: Coloquei isso, mas aí, ele exclui o id, e o filho dele, ou seja, acaba excluindo tudo.

Comment: Se está atualizando os ids de relacionamento antes de excluir, não tem motivo para excluir estes filhos também. No seu Model, onde foi declarado esse relacionamento, a propriedade `dependent` está definida como **false**?

Comment: Meu model está só assim:`public $useTable = 'navigation';
    
    public $displayField = 'nome';
    
    public $actsAs = array('Tree');` Eu realmente não entendi o porque de quando eu excluo o id, ele exclui todos os parents_id que estão relacionado á ele.